# Error "Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, error-handling

Getting an error with this piece of code 
"Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled"

I am using the Xcode 7.1 the latest beta and swift 2.0

```
func checkUserCredentials() -> Bool {
    PFUser.logInWithUsername(userName!, password: password!)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        return true
    }
    return false
```

[image]

Comment: Do { try PFUser.login ..... } catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription) }

Comment: What is the full written out code to replace mine in that segment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Swift 2.0 introduces [error handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508).  The error indicates that `logInWithUsername:password:` can potentially throw an error, and you must do something with that error.  You have one of a few options:

Mark your `checkUserCredentials()` functional as `throws` and propagate the error to the caller:

```
func checkUserCredentials() throws -> Bool {
    try PFUser.logInWithUsername(userName!, password: password!)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Use `do`/`catch` syntax to catch the potential error:

```
func checkUserCredentials() -> Bool {
    do {
        try PFUser.logInWithUsername(userName!, password: password!)
    }
    catch _ {
        // Error handling
    }

    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Use the `try!` keyword to have the program trap if an error is thrown, this is only appropriate if you know for a fact the function will never throw given the current circumstances - similar to using `!` to force unwrap an optional (seems unlikely given the method name):

```
func checkUserCredentials() -> Bool {
    try! PFUser.logInWithUsername(userName!, password: password!)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: where in my code does that all go. I am very new to this.

Comment: @RobertS The answer provides the code for you. You have to precede your `PFUser.logInWithUsername` call with `try`. The answer does a very good job of explaining this. :)

Comment: @RobertS This is three different versions of the function you provided, depending on what you need to happen.  I suggest you follow the link to the documentation and check it out for details.

Comment: @Charles A. Excellent job. Worked! Thanks!