# Errors thrown from here are not handled in swift 2 xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

i run my my old code in xcode 7 
"var fetchedObjects:[AnyObject]? = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)" have error with "Errors thrown from here are not handled" how to fix it?

```
   @IBAction func SaveImage(sender: AnyObject) {

    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext

    var error:NSError?

    //声明数据的请求
    var fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10 //限定查询结果的数量
    fetchRequest.fetchOffset = 0 //查询的偏移量

    //声明一个实体结构
    var entity:NSEntityDescription? = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User",
        inManagedObjectContext: context)
    //设置数据请求的实体结构
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    //设置查询条件
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id= '1' ", "")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    //查询操作
    var fetchedObjects:[AnyObject]? = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

    //遍历查询的结果
    for info:Content in fetchedObjects as! [Content]{
        println("id=\(info.id)")
        println("username=\(info.username)")
        println("password=\(info.password)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997955/error-call-can-throw-but-is-not-marked-with-try-and-the-error-is-not-handled/32998154#32998154

Comment: What does this question have to do with Xcode, core-data, or iOS?  I tried to make an edit to remove those tags, but then SO forced me to edit the content, so I bailed.

Comment: @Jody Hagins i want to save data in coredata.but swift2.0 has change

Answer (score 0):

i fix it , use this code

```
 do {
    let fetchedObjects = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

    //遍历查询的结果
    for info:Content in fetchedObjects as! [Content]{
        print("id=\(info.contentName)")
        info.photo_1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
        //item!.photo_1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageHolder.image!)
        }

        try self.moc.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```